# Best implementation type for choice group with large number of choices

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am trying to implement an React component as shown in the picture. What would be the best implementation type to go for this? Choice group(https://fabricweb.z5.web.core.windows.net/oufr/7.155.3/#/examples/choicegroup) seems like an option, but according to the best practice, if the total number of choices is more than 7, a drop-down should be used. In my scenario, there could be more than 50+ versions.

Any ideas? Would appreciate your thoughts. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: I don't know which component you use for grid but I think DetailsList component with multiselect is a good fit for this scenario. If you don't plan to use DetailsList it's better to use Checkbox then Option.

Comment: Thanks! I used DetailsList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DetailsList component with multiselect is a good fit for this scenario

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).